# Django Swagger won't allow me to use POST method (no parameters shown)

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, swagger

I'm using `djangorestframework` together with `drf-spectacular` modules for a Django project, and I'm trying to build some basic API methods for my `Project` model. Its structure looks like this:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.URLField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I also have a serializer for the model, looking like this:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from api.models.Project import Project


class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'image', 'date']
```

Then, in `views.py`, I created two functions: `project_list_view`, which either lets you to GET all the `Project` objects from the database, or lets you POST a new object. And finally, `project_detail_view`, which lets you GET a `Project` object by typing in its `pk` (integer `id`). These are my two functions:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def project_list_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        projects = Project.objects.all()
        serializer = ProjectSerializer(projects, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == "POST":
        serializer = ProjectSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

@api_view(['GET'])
def project_detail_view(request, pk):
    if request.method == "GET":
        try:
            project = Project.objects.get(pk = pk)
            serializer = ProjectSerializer(project, many = False)
            return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

The GET from `project_list_view` and `project_detail_view` work, but my problem lays in the POST method.
My Swagger is set to display its API Schema when accessing http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs/, and as I said, GET methods work properly, but when I'm trying to click on "Try it out" at the POST method, the fields are not displayed. I can only press "Execute" without actually being able to complete anything. After I click on "Execute", Swagger returns a `404 Bad Request` response.

This is how POST looks like in Swagger:

[image]

My question is: Why won't Swagger display fields for each parameter of the model? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swagger Grabs the fields from a **serializer_class** variable.
I really recommend you change the format to Class-Based Views.
Something using [mixins or generic class.](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/#using-mixins)

Your view could be like

```py
class ProjectView(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, ] 
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
    queryset = Project.objects.all()

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

[More on Mixins and Generic Views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but I want to learn how to use function based views first. I would like to firstly get used to the "low-level" stuff. Isn't it possible for me to use the same function based view, but edit the serializer in some certain way?

Comment: I appreciate your efforts to try to learn function based views. But I highly recommend migrate to Class Based Views, Works better with 3rd parties like swagger, and brings a lot to your project like reusability, implicit code, faster development, etc. I believe that's a way to manually describe the body of post request on swagger. unfortunately I don't know...

Comment: Thank you. Switched the POST method to a class-based view. Also marked your answer as a response!